# Should I pause mirroring when I reboot the witness server?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

So I know that when patching the two main database servers (SQL Server for the record) you do the mirror, failover and then when it's all caught up do the new mirror, but what about the witness box? Is it safe just to patch and then restart it and (in theory) it will just pick up again?

Comment: Everything is clearly documented in [How to install SP and CU on instance that is configured to use DB Mirroring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926824)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must do this in order if you want to update the Principal, Mirror and Witness:

1. Switch from `high-performance mode` to `high safety mode` (if you are using this mode)
2. Remove the **Witness**
3. Upgrade the **Witness** (anytime between 2 and 9, see below)
4. Upgrade the **Mirror**(s)
5. Wait until **Mirror**(s) is(are) synchronized and manually fail **Primary** over
6. Upgrade the **Primary**
7. Upgrade the **Witness** (if not already done between 2 and 9)
8. Switch back to `high-performance mode` (if required)
9. Add the **Witness**